# When statement with two variables kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to make this `when` statement with two Integers. I tried to do it this way:

```
when(row && column) {
     in 0..2 -> end = true;
     else -> {
         end = false;
         println("Invalid move!")
     }
}
```

but it didn't work.
Is there any way to do this? There are obviously many other ways to do this, but I want my code clean and readable, and this would be very helpful to accomplish that.

Comment: what do you want to do with `row && column`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No this isn't possible. Especially, `int && int` is no valid syntax.

Alternatively, you could express this code like this:

```
end = if (setOf(row, column).all { it in 0..2 })
    true
else
    false.also { println("Invalid move!") }
```

I’m not a big fan of substituting `if` with `when` for such basic cases but that’s a matter of taste.

Answer (score 10):

Why don't do it the regulr way?

```
when {
    row in 0..2 && column in 0..2-> end = true;
    else -> {
        end = false;
        println("Invalid move!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
when (row) {
  in 0..2 -> if (column in 0..2) end = true
  else -> {
    end = false
    println("Invalid move!")
  }
}
```